# Opener rebid priority

Tags: bridge, bidding

I'm playing/studying SAYC. So I know that game in major comes first then notrump then game in minors.

When I open with 1 Club partner responds with 1 Spade -- I have 18PTS and 4 hearts and NT distribution, should I bid 2Hhearts, 3Hearts, or 1NT?

Answer (score 5):

With SAYC a balanced hand would [normally be bid](http://www.onent.com/handouts/natural_notrump.htm) as follows:

- 13-14 points - open 1 of a suit then rebid 1NT
- 15-17 points - open 1NT
- 18-19 points - open 1 of a suit then rebid 2NT
- 20-21 points - open 2NT

Your rebid should be 2NT. If you bid this, your partner has a very good idea of what you've got and can then decide how best to proceed.

It's also worth noting that when your partner responded he should have been "[bidding up the line](http://home.comcast.net/~kwbridge/up.htm)". So if he had the same number of hearts and spades, he would bid hearts rather than spades. A heart fit is therefore unlikely.

Comment: +1: 2NT is the right bid. Even with 5-4 spades-hearts, partner can always bid 3H to find a heart fit.

Comment: @Tom77: why unlikely? Assume he has 5 spades, and 4 hearts. He bid spade first (according to your link (http://home.comcast.net/~kwbridge/up.htm):  "If you have suits of unequal length, you should still show your longer one first.")).

Comment: Note that 3NT is NOT generally bid with stronger hands than 21 balanced points. As these would have been opened either 2NT or 2C, 3NT can be reserved for a game-forcing system bid showing spade support of some sort.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: No, 3NT is "usually" rebid with a long club suit (at least in SAYC I think).

Comment: (long club suit which you expect to run, that is).

Answer (score 2):

You should rebid 2NT. Your partner is unlikely to have 4 hearts, though it is still possible for 5-4 or 5-5 majors. He should have bidden 1♥ for 4-4 majors.

The 2NT rebid often makes you the declarer, hiding your strong hand. You will not lose 4-4 heart fit since he can bid 3♥ for 4 hearts (and hence 5 spades). If your partner were the declarer, 4M is *less scary* than 3NT.

Consequently, 2♥ reverse is for **unbalanced** hands. With an unbalanced hand, you dislike dangerous 3NT. This also promises 5+ clubs. (With 0-3 spades, 4+ hearts, 2-4 clubs, the hand is either balanced or an 1♦ opener.)  You are more likely to go to a correct club contract, such as 5♣ or slams.

I also suggest 3♥ jump reverse for 6 clubs and 5 hearts without game-forcing values. It takes up much space, but it precisely describes hands difficult to bid. With game-forcing values, you have unambiguous "2♥ reverse then 3♥".